# Python Bokeh - Chart plots correctly in a browser only

Tags: python, plot, browser, charts, bokeh

I am plotting shapefiles (i.e. maps) using bokeh Python package. However, the final chart I get does plots 100% correctly on a computer (win 7, internet explorer) but it does not plot on another computer with the same configuration. Is there some Python/Bokeh/InternetExplorer settings or whatever that I am missing ? The issue does happen even if I am moving to Chrome/Firefox: on one computer it all works fine in fact Bokeh code runs and opens the browser with a chart in it, on the other computer the same exact code executes correctly, Bokeh opens the browser but with NO CHART in it !

Comment: So you don't see anything at all? Are there any errors in the console? Maybe something gets blocked by firewall or a javascript blocker?

Comment: Hello syntonym ! Yes, I see nothing at all even if the browser loads the bokeh html file taking the time needed to do so...any idea ? How can I see if some error loads up inside the console ? Thanks a million...

Comment: In firefox if you press f12 it will open the developer tools. There "network" (for which you probably have to reload, hit f5) and "console" are interesting. The network tab will show you if anything gets blocked i.e. by a firewall. The console will show you any javascript errors. Does the same happen with a much simpler bokeh chart e.g. just a simple line?

Comment: Syntonmym thank you so much for your help, I found the issue: it was the local firewall that blocked my bokeh to get http online data ! Using the F12 command in Firefox I solved it out ! Thanks a million